# How to handle table names as variables in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble running the following SQL select statement in my SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SELECT @percapCount = count(socSecNo)
FROM @percapHistPrev
```

It doesn't seem to understand what `@percapHistPrev` and `socsecno` are. I already declared both `@percapCount` and `@percapHistPrev` in the stored procedure.

The following statement works just above it

```
SELECT @memberCount = count(socSecNo)
FROM member
```

I am guessing trying to use the table name as a variable is the problem. So how can I fix the statement to make it work?

Comment: Could you post the whole stored procedure please.

Comment: You **cannot** use parameters for your table and/or column names - only for values. If you really insist on doing this, you'll have to use **dynamic SQL** (building up your statement as a string variable, then "executing" that string variable) - which has its inherent drawbacks and shortcomings, too.

Comment: @marc_s i tried dynamic sql. the stored procedure compiles ok but upon running it tells me i must declare the scalar variable -/@percapCount.  SET .@tsql = 'SELECT .@percapCount = Count(socSecNo) from ' + .@percapHistPrev

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the output parameter and the sp_executeSQL call.   For example

```
DECLARE @ctr int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @tblName varchar(30);

SET @tblName='member'
SET @ctr = 0
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @ctrOUT = count(SocSecNo) FROM '+@tblName 
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ctrOUT int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @ctrOUT=@ctr OUTPUT;
SELECT @ctr
```